# Apache POI - Generated Date Not Sortable Accordingly

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Using Apache POI API, I have been able to generate correctly integers and floats on Excel. I can verify they are correct especially when I use the Sort function.

I simply cast values to their respective type, and the API takes care of the rest.

However, this technique didn't work with dates (I convert them to `java.util.Date`), they are correctly formatted, but the sorting is not accurate.

Any suggestions?

I tried two alternatives:

The first one: `cell.setCellValue(new Date(value));`

The second one: `cell.setCellValue(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date(value)));`

Comment: Are you using one of the [BuiltinFormats](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html) for date?

Comment: No, the date comes formatted from SQL.

Comment: You may need to set the format explicitly as shown in [createDateCells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells). The date format to be set is one of the BuiltInFormats.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to create the date cells? You might be doing something wrong there, but with no code it's hard for us to tell...

Comment: Question updated with the code included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your code in reverse order:

```
cell.setCellValue(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date(value)));
```

Don't do this. It converts the date to a string, much as if in Excel you went into a cell and typed `'01/01/2010` - with the `'` on the front forcing to a string

```
cell.setCellValue(new Date(value));
```

This is nearly there. You need to follow the [POI instructions on creating a date cell](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells), and also format the cell to be a Date Cell in your desired date format

eg for `dd/mm/yyyy`, once near the top of your file do this:

```
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
CellStyle dateCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(
    createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Then for your cell set + style it with

```
cell.setCellValue(new Date(value));
cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
```

Comment: Man, you're awesome. Thanks for the abundant answer!